# Dynamically create multiple ImageButton controls and wire-up Click event

Tags: asp.net

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET. Please forgive me for my knowledge :) Assuming I want to create 4 imagebuttons. If I click on any imagebutton, it will move me to another page with different STT (<- just a name).
Here's my code:

```
    for (int i= 0; i< 4; i++)
            {
                ImageButton image = new ImageButton();
                image.Click += (s, args) =>
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("~/Showroom.aspx?STT=" + (i));
                    };
               //other things to do
            }
```

Now the problem is that when I click on any imagebutton. I'll be redirected to Showroom.aspx with STT = 4 (which is i after the loop). How can I be redirected to the page with desired STT.

EDIT:
Just to clarify. What I want is Clicking on imagebutton 1 will move me to Showroom.aspx with STT = 0. Imagebutton 2 will move me to the page with STT=1 and so on.

Comment: Does this work? If not, what happens?

Comment: As I said. It always redirect me to Showroom.aspx with STT = 4 (which is i after the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

`"~/Showroom.aspx?STT=" + (i)` means it captures the variable `i` rather than its value at the time of delegates creation.

### Solution

Create ***url*** outside of delegate.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    string url = string.Format("~/Showroom.aspx?STT={0}", i);
    var image = new ImageButton();
    image.Click += (s, args) => Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy i to a local variable.  Or as the other Answer suggests, build your URL before its used in your lambda expression.

```
            int x = i;
            image.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Showroom.aspx?STT=" + (x));
            };
```

Comment: Yeah! It works. I didn't think of storing it as a local variable :)